# Не получается преобразовать типы при выводе изображений из БД

Tags: c#, база-данных, asp.net-mvc

Два дня просидел над проблемой. Никак не могу понять, как всё-таки преобразовать байтовый массив в изображение при выводе. Выдает ошибку: не удается преобразовать из "string" в "System.ReadOnlySpan".

Вот контроллер:

```
// выгружаем фото из БД
public static void ReadFileFromDatabase()
{
    // #region не работает но и ошибок нет
    string connectionString = @"data source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=OpafotoDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework";
    List<Image> images = new List<Image>();
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Images";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
            string filename = reader.GetString(1);
            string title = reader.GetString(2);
            byte[] data = (byte[])reader.GetValue(3);

            Image image = new Image(id, filename, title, data);
            images.Add(image);
        }
    }

    // сохраним первый файл из списка
    // images[0].Data выводить на фронт
    if (images.Count > 0)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(images[0].FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            fs.Write(images[0].Data, 0, images[0].Data.Length);
            res = images[0].Data;
        }
    }
}
```

Так пытаюсь получить во view:

```
@model List<string>

@*<h3>В списке @Model.Count элемента</h3>*@
@foreach (var country in Model) {
    <img src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(country)" />
}
```

Comment: [`Image`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image?view=netframework-4.8) - Это абстрактный класс, поэтому нельзя писать `new Image`

Comment: Что такое `Image`? Явно какой-то самописный класс. Покажите его.

Comment: В какой строке ошибка? В контроллере или во вью?